# How to sort a struct using qsort?

Tags: c, sorting

I have a struct declared like this

```
struct data
{
char * Date;
char * String;
};
struct data **RegArray = NULL;

int ArrayCount = 0;
```

I add new items to the array this way:

```
struct data **tmp = ( struct data ** )realloc( RegArray, ( ArrayCount + 1 ) * sizeof( struct data * ) );
if ( tmp == NULL )
{
    printf( "\nRealloc failed!" );
    return;
}
RegArray = tmp;

RegArray[ ArrayCount ] = ( struct data * )malloc( sizeof **RegArray );
if ( RegArray[ ArrayCount ] == NULL )
{
    printf( "\nMalloc failed!" );
    return;
}

RegArray[ ArrayCount ]->Date = _strdup( cDate );
RegArray[ ArrayCount ]->String = _strdup( cString );

ArrayCount++;
```

The function which compares the values:

```
int CompareByDate( const void *elem1, const void *elem2 )
{
//return ( ( data* )elem1 )->Date > ( ( data* )elem2 )->Date ? 1 : -1;
return strcmp( ( ( data* )elem1 )->Date, ( ( data* )elem2 )->Date );

}//CompareByDate
```

And finally I call qsort like this:

```
qsort( RegArray, ArrayCount-1, sizeof( data ), CompareByDate );
```

The problem is, that the data won't be sorted. 
So what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to tag this as C rather than C++. There is little need to deal with this kind of thing in C++.

Comment: [Please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Comment: @unwind: I know, that I shouldn't do that, but otherwise Visual Studio won't compile.

Comment: Why use `struct data **` when you only allocate a single `data` structure? Why not simple `struct data * = realloc(...)`? Changing this would incidentally make your `qsort` *and* comparison function work as expected.

Comment: Is it okay to `realloc` before you `malloc`?  Is that what you're doing?

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey If the pointer passed to `realloc` is `NULL` then it works just like `malloc`.

Comment: @kampi Then you're not compiling as C, but as C++. They're different languages, it's rarely a good idea to do this, even deliberately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `qsort` call and comparison function, you forget that you're dealing with an "array" of pointers. The easiest change is to *not* use an array of pointers:

```
struct data *RegArray = NULL;

/* ... */

struct data *tmp = realloc( RegArray, ( ArrayCount + 1 ) * sizeof( struct data ) );
if ( tmp == NULL )
{
    printf( "\nRealloc failed!" );
    return;
}
RegArray = tmp;

RegArray[ ArrayCount ].Date = _strdup( cDate );
RegArray[ ArrayCount ].String = _strdup( cString );

ArrayCount++;
```

This will make your `qsort` call (and comparison function) work as they are shown in the question.

---

If you don't want to change the code as outlined above, you have to change the `qsort` call and comparison function:

```
qsort( RegArray, ArrayCount-1, sizeof( data * ), CompareByDate );

/* ... */

int CompareByDate( const void *elem1, const void *elem2 )
{
    struct data **d1 = (struct data **) elem1;
    struct data **d2 = (struct data **) elem2;

    return strcmp((*d1)->Date, (*d2)->Date);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That solved the problem, however I made one more mistake. When calling qsort I used ArrayCount-1, and it should be only ArrayCount.